# A webservice call returned me a xml of 1000 workers. How can I split the file into multiple xml files containing 50 workers each using XSLT?

Tags: xml, xslt, split

I have a xml file which is having 1000 workers with xpath env:Envelope/env:Body/wd:Get_Workers_Response/wd:Response_Data/wd:Worker

I need to split the file into multiple files based on the number of worker, say 50, using XSLT

My webservice response:

```
        <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <env:Envelope xmlns:env="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">
        <env:Body>
            <wd:Get_Workers_Response xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc" wd:version="v35.1">
                <wd:Response_Filter>
                    <wd:As_Of_Effective_Date>2021-01-04</wd:As_Of_Effective_Date>
                    <wd:As_Of_Entry_DateTime>2021-01-04T23:28:03.113-08:00</wd:As_Of_Entry_DateTime>
                    <wd:Page>1</wd:Page>
                    <wd:Count>100</wd:Count>
                </wd:Response_Filter>
                <wd:Response_Results>
                    <wd:Total_Results>2</wd:Total_Results>
                    <wd:Total_Pages>1</wd:Total_Pages>
                    <wd:Page_Results>2</wd:Page_Results>
                    <wd:Page>1</wd:Page>
                </wd:Response_Results>
                <wd:Response_Data>
                    <wd:Worker>
                        <wd:Worker_Data>
                            <wd:Worker_ID>1</wd:Worker_ID>
                            <wd:Name>aaaaaa</wd:Name>
                        </wd:Worker_Data>
                    </wd:Worker>
                    <wd:Worker>
                        <wd:Worker_Data>
                            <wd:Worker_ID>2</wd:Worker_ID>
                            <wd:Name>bbbbbb</wd:Name>
                        </wd:Worker_Data>
                    </wd:Worker>
                    <wd:Worker>
                        <wd:Worker_Data>
                            <wd:Worker_ID>3</wd:Worker_ID>
                            <wd:Name>cccccc</wd:Name>
                        </wd:Worker_Data>
                    </wd:Worker>

.....
..... 998 more workers
```

Desired Output:

File 1:
Worker 1 to 50

```
                    <wd:Worker>
                        <wd:Worker_Data>
                            <wd:Worker_ID>1</wd:Worker_ID>
                            <wd:Name>aaaaaa</wd:Name>
                        </wd:Worker_Data>
                    </wd:Worker>
                    <wd:Worker>
                        <wd:Worker_Data>
                            <wd:Worker_ID>2</wd:Worker_ID>
                            <wd:Name>bbbbbb</wd:Name>
                        </wd:Worker_Data>
                    </wd:Worker>
...
...
                    <wd:Worker>
                        <wd:Worker_Data>
                            <wd:Worker_ID>50</wd:Worker_ID>
                            <wd:Name>xxxxx</wd:Name>
                        </wd:Worker_Data>
                    </wd:Worker>
```

File 2:
Worker 51 to 100
......

My XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform"
    xmlns:xs="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema"
    xmlns:wd="urn:com.workday/bsvc"
    exclude-result-prefixes="xs"
    version="2.0">
    
    <xsl:template match="wd:Response_Data">
        <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Worker" group-adjacent="(position()-1) idiv 50">
            <xsl:result-document href="batch{position()}.xml">
                <batch nr="{position()}">
                    <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
                </batch>
            </xsl:result-document>
        </xsl:for-each-group>
    </xsl:template>
    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In XSLT 2.0+

```
<xsl:template match="wd:Response_Data">
  <xsl:for-each-group select="wd:Worker" group-adjacent="(position()-1) idiv 50">
    <xsl:result-document href="batch{position()}.xml">
      <batch nr="{position()}">
        <xsl:copy-of select="current-group()"/>
      </batch>
    </xsl:result-document>
  </xsl:for-each-group>
</xsl:template>
```

Comment: Thanks. But will this create multiple files? I got just one file with unreadable data:
"<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>30896d7c91ca01f31590418279114e08xxxxxxxx0002021-01-112021-01-11T04:10:41.162-08:001501111110000000000000111111111111111111111111111110000000011717130896d7c91ca017bb7a30642da11afe7116xxx78Mxxxxx xxxx11677781167778d903bb3fedad45039383f6de334ad4dbAUAUS3626dcb8d19b4101c624a8e156ad0fdf93NAME_VALUE_TYP_xxxxxxxxx903bb3fedad450393xxxx6de334ad4dbAxxxx36Mexxxxxxxx26dcb8d19b41012xxxxd7d848b30f919xxx_FEMALE"

Comment: Yes, this will create multiple files if you run it correctly with an XSLT 2.0 processor and correct invocation. If you tell us in more detail what you are doing, then we can tell you where you went wrong. There are many things you might have done wrong, for example declaring the namespace incorrectly.

Comment: I have edited my question above. Please have a look. I am using the XSLT in Workday Studio

Comment: I've never used Workday Studio, but I believe it allows you to configure what XSLT processor is used. Check that you are actually using XSLT 2.0. Also check that if it's writing multiple output files, you know where they are going. It might be worth using an absolute file URI in the href attribute instead of a relative URI if you're not sure.